# Where can I find the class: AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead for Apache Beam implementation?

Tags: java, scala, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to implement Apache Beam with GCP Dataflow using this [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java) given by Google.

In the available templates, I am using JdbcToBigquery which is my usecase.
These are the dependencies I have in pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.base</groupId>
  <artifactId>Deltaflow</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.13.1</scala.version>
    <beam.version>2.28.0</beam.version>
    <threetenbp.version>1.4.4</threetenbp.version>
    <beam-vendor-guava.version>0.1</beam-vendor-guava.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-vendor-guava-20_0</artifactId>
      <version>${beam-vendor-guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
      <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
      <version>${threetenbp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>Deltaflow</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>assemble-all</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Inside the template, there is class: DynamicJdbcIO.java which helps creating creating jdbc connection. It could be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/io/DynamicJdbcIO.java)

I have added all the beam related jars in my pom.xml file. But some how I am facing an error at this part of the code in DynamicJdbcIO.java class:

```
  public static <T> DynamicRead<T> read() {
    return new AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead.Builder<T>().build();
  }
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead'
```

I also added these external jars just to make sure I have all the libraries.

1. auto-service-1.0-rc7.jar
2. auto-value-1.7.4.jar
3. google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-2.5.0.jar
4. google-cloud-kms-1.41.1.jar
5. mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar
6. proto-google-cloud-kms-v1-0.88.1.jar
7. sqljdbc42-6.0.8112.jar

Could anyone please let me know what am I missing here ? Is this a dependency version mismatch or is there a jar file or a dependency available for `AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In IntelliJ? The `AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead` class is part of the AutoValue nested builder in the DynamicJdbcIO.java code you linked [1]. I wouldn't expect that it is a dependency issue because of that, but if it is IntelliJ it may just that you need to add that source code into your project by adding it in the project explorer and marking it as a source. [1]: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/92d3f3062856c3fb1aede24e4c12411ef7a29dc1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/io/DynamicJdbcIO.java#L124

Comment: I understand that and the error is on IntelliJ. The problem here is I am not able to find tha class anywhere. I tried to give the package name, jar name and the class name itself in Google but no search result contains the source code of the class. 
What should I do ?

Comment: Since AutoValue generates code, you need to compile the project, then find where that generated code is and add it to your project by right clicking on the directory in the project explorer and marking it as a source. Another option that could work, though I haven't tried it myself, is to use the AutoValue plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8091-autovalue-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this error? Does this error occur when compiling maven project in IDE (VS Code, IntelliJ ..) ?

In my opinion you should add dependencies to pom.xml file

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
  <version>${autovalue.service.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
  <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
  <version>${autovalue.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
  <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${autovalue.annotations.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Version from data flow template:

```
<autovalue.service.version>1.0-rc6</autovalue.service.version>   
<autovalue.annotations.version>1.7.4</autovalue.annotations.version>
<autovalue.version>1.7.4</autovalue.version>
```